# Graphics issue: Is it a motorcycle or just a bush/tree?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Everytime I see a **black motorcycle-kinda-shape** from far distance, but when I get really close to it 90% of time I find out it's just a **bush/tree**.

Is there any settings which can help me see trees from distance with their legit colours and shape and not as black motorcycle-kinda-shape? Is this just my graphics card issue or general game graphics issue?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot as an example?

Comment: @StevenDavison yes, once I get home and in game, sorry for posting without screen

Comment: Seems like a graphics setting issue, I usually spot "players" in the distance only to scope in and find it was a bush/tree.

Comment: Even with a high resolution and maximum settings, there is always a distance at which a bunch of dark pixels looks like another bunch of dark pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that AntiAlias at higher level can mitigate the issue or alternatively 120% render size with lower AntiAlias . I will try this later and try to get some screenshot